# Join SQL query with double quotes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query in PHP.

```
Select count(*) as total from ( select a.name,b.email from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.emailId ) myTable
```

I want to write it in quotes as

```
$sql = "select count(*) as total from ( select a.name,b.email from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.emailId ) myTable"
```

But I get an error. 
How to handle single and double quotes while writing in PHP?

Comment: what error you get? You can use single and double quotes, but in php you must have ';' at end of line..., you should use 'as' before aliases

Comment: @AdamSilenko #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Your error is an SQL syntax error and not an error related to the use of quotes.

Comment: @AdamSilenko How you use single and double quotes in query thats what i don't know :(

Comment: Show the error and the actual code that produces it. You never know , you might spot the missing `;` while writing a proper question.

Comment: use mysql_error to see details of error

Comment: @YvesLeBorg since im using double quotes for outer select statement,It considers inside select statement as string which is want i want to be fixed

Comment: Either show the error or explain what you want properly.... To use single & double quote is like: $sql = 'select * from table where id="'.$id.'"'; OR $sql = "select * from table where id='".$id."'"

Answer (score 1):

The query you have written is syntactically incorrect in MySQL.  It needs an alias for the subquery:

```
Select count(*) as total
from (select a.name, b.email
      from table1 a inner join
           table2 b
           on a.id = b.emailId
     ) ab
-------^
```

However, the subquery is unnecessary, so I would advise:

```
      select count(*)
      from table1 a inner join
           table2 b
           on a.id = b.emailId
```

Comment: Actually he have an alias to the subquery `MyTable`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I have edited that i just want to know how to handle single and double quotes so that query is executed

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know how to use quotes, read about [strings in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score -1):

Your query is currently incorrect. But, to build the query in PHP you can use double quotes, and then use single quotes to use strings like below:

Edit:

```
$my_name = 'HarshMakadia'; 
$sql = "SELECT id, name, description FROM your_table WHERE name ='".$my_name."'";
```

Comment: Yes short would be `WHERE name = '$my_name'` and this is not a question about security, sql injection, prepared statements. All he wanted to know is how to use single and double quotes.